# What Reference Set is Excel VBA's "Application.Worksheetfunction" In?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, reference

I am writing code in VBA for MS Access which opens and manipulates ranges and data in Excel worksheets. I've found the reference library (from Tools > References) that allow me to reference Excel objects like ranges, cells, etc. Now I want to take the average of a range but this would normally require use of the Application.Worksheetfunction class which does not seem to have been a member of the Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library. Which reference library would give me access to these functions?

Comment: `Worksheetfunction` is a member of `Excel.Application` - you can check in the Object Browser

Comment: ..if you're having problems with `WorksheetFunction` maybe show what code you tried and explain what issues you had with it.  Compile error?  Run-time error?

Comment: No issues with using worksheet function just needed to know which reference libary I needed to access it since VBA in MS Access uses different default libraries than VBA in Excel. Using Excel.Application worked after I added the library in the answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an image of all of the references that I use for VBA in Excel.  I opened Access and by default the reference "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" wasn't added.

[Click here to see list of references that I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOTQ1.png)

Comment: This, along with @Tim Williams comment on using Excel.Application solved my issue. Thanks!